# cURL command to upload file does not upload file

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload

So I have a Java API and I use cURL commands to send GET/POST requests to my API. I'm using Springboot in my Java API. My cURL command looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://localhost:8443/abc/code/v \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F file=@/path/to/file.txt
```

and my Java Springboot method that receives this request looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{code}/{v}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadTemplate( //
            @ApiParam(value = "code desc") //
            @PathVariable final String code, //
            @ApiParam(value = "v desc") //
            @PathVariable final String v, //
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
        //log.info("received [url: /tabc/" + code + "/" + v + ", method: POST");
        System.out.println("file: "+ file.getName());
}
```

which prints out `"file: file"`

It doesn't look like `file.txt` is uploaded to the server at all! What am I doing wrong? I've looked up on Google but it looks like I'm doing nearly everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MultipartFile.getName`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getName--) returns the name of the  parameter in the multipart form.

To get the bytes of the `MultipartFile` use [`file.getBytes()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getBytes--)

And if your `MultipartFile` is a text file you could use this utility method to retrieve a list of the lines in that text file:

```
    public List<String> read(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in)) {
            return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56177035)

Comment: OH! I didn't know that! But what does this return and why is it `List<String>`

Comment: The utility method I included reads a text file (I assumed that's what you were reading since you used `/path/to/file.txt` in your request) and returns a list of lines found in the text as a `List<String>`.

Comment: OH! `file.txt` was just an example I used. I'll be sending various types of file so I guess I have to use an appropriate method for `reader`. Also, can I not extract the file name/extension?

Comment: Or you could use `file.getBytes()`. I edited the answer to accordingly.